# verificar se um link de video ainda esta funcionando

Tags: javascript, html, html5, vídeo, html5-video

estou desenvolvendo um site e uso um link q em tempo em tempo Fica off, ja tenho o sistema que rodo para atualizar esse link porem ele esta em modo manual para rodar. queria saber se tem algum modo de verificar se o link do video esta off ou not font tipo ver a resposta do codigo

```
 <video controls>
      <source src="<?= link que vem do banco de dados ?>" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que não é exatamente o que quer, mas pode te ajudar caso não encontre uma solução

A tag `<video>` tem uma atributo chamado `poster` que serve como uma "capa" para o vídeo. Essa imagem vai aparecer antes de vc dar play, então mesmo se o vídeo não carregar essa imagem vai aparecer. Dessa forma vc consegue pelo menos dar um feedback mais controlado caso tenha esse problema de carregamento.

Nesse exemplo abaixo nenhum dos dois vídeos não vão carregar, mas vai aparecer a imagem que está definida no poster (https://placecage.com/320/240).

```html
<video controls width="320" height="240" poster="https://placecage.com/320/240" >
  <source src="movie1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie2.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

---

**Opção 2**

Outra opção é usar o próprio `source` para deixar um vídeo de *fallback* para o primeiro. Repare que no código abaixo eu tenho dois vídeo, o primeiro vai falhar o carregamento, e então o segundo que vai aparecer como opção para ser tocado. Então vc pode manter no seu servidor um vídeo seguro, que sempre vai funcionar e deixa-lo de fallback caso o vídeo dinâmico falhe no carregamento.

Repare que a tag que tem o php não vai carregar, e o vídeo do *fallback* vai ficar disponível para vc dar play

```html
<video controls width="320" height="240"  >
   <source src="<?= link que vem do banco de dados ?>" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: tem como ao inves de imagem eu solicitar uma pagina?

Comment: @CyberHacker cara eu atualizei a resposta, tinha me equivocado em algumas coisas, além disso coloquei uma explicação de como fazer um fallback direito de videos. Sobre solicitar uma nova página acredito que talvez seja possível sim, até com JS, casso algo não carregue na página e de algum erro te encaminha para outra página... Ai seria bom vc editar a pergunta tb, falando que essa tb seria uma resposta para vc